# simple python asyncio server does not read data

Tags: python-asyncio

I am using python3.6 and asyncio on windows10 to make a simple server. I have problem getting the server to work the way I want. 
But the same server implemented with the socket interface works as expected. 
Here is the working server

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 3201))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Client connection: {}:{}'.format(*addr))
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print('recv {} bytes'.format(len(data)))
            else:
                print('no data')
                break
print('connection closed')
```

I test it with the nc command. e.g.

```
nc 10.68.100.32 3201
abc
ab
a
^C
```

The server print:

```
Client connection: 10.68.101.87:55243
recv 4 bytes
recv 3 bytes
recv 2 bytes
no data
connection closed
```

But I can't to do the same server with asyncio.
Here is a protocol version:

```
import asyncio

class ListenServer(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        address = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('connection made by client:{}:{}'.format(*address))

    def data_deceived(self, data):
        print('received {}'.format(len(data)), flush=True)

    def eof_received(self):
        print('print received EOF')

    def connection_lost(self, error):
        if error:
            print('ERROR: {}'.format(error))
        else:
            print('connection closed')

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
factory = event_loop.create_server(ListenServer, '', 3201)
server = event_loop.run_until_complete(factory)

event_loop.run_forever()
print('closing server')
server.close()
```

For the same nc test sequence as above server writes:

```
connection made by client:10.68.101.87:55247
print received EOF
connection closed
```

I also fail with the asyncio coroutine API verion of the server:

```
import asyncio

async def just_read(reader, writer):
    cli_host, cli_port = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print('Client connected {}:{}'.format(cli_host, cli_port))
    while True:
        data = await reader.read()
        if data:
            print('received {} bytes'.format(len(data)), flush=True)
        else:
            print('closing')
            writer.close()
            return

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(just_read, '', 3201, loop=event_loop)
server = event_loop.run_until_complete(coro)

event_loop.run_forever()
server.close()
print('Connection closed')
```

The output in this case is a litle differet:

```
Client connected 10.68.101.87:55253
received 9 bytes
closing
```

In this case I get all the data when I close down nc with ^C, 
and the server continues so I can connect again.

I want the server to read and print out what the client writes,
it shall connect once and keep the connection as long as the client is connected. 
How can I achieve this with asyncio, shall I use protocol or coroutine version, does it matter?

And this is only the first, and probably simplest, of several tasks I want the server to do.
Other tasks not shown here are start a periodic sending of a dummy message 
and send response on different messages.

Comment: While this isn't a fix but rather a suggestion, I would strongly recommend using a framework like Sanic for async servers. Tends to be more robust

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a _minimal_ example that reproduces the problem. Take away anything not strictly necessary, e.g. `struct.pack` and so on. Also, please specify how you are testing the server. Are you connecting with one client, or with more than one? Does a client ever disconnect? Does the client read the messages written by the server?
 When do the exceptions start occurring?

Comment: What I meant is, simplify the server to only write simple ASCII messages, and connect to it using `nc`. If this works correctly, then try to determine the difference between the small example and the real example. If it doesn't work, then edit the question to include (only) the smaller server and steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user4815162342, good suggestion! I am working on a simpler version, and will post it as new question and link to it from here.

Comment: It's ultimately up to you, but I would suggest to simply edit this question. As it stands now, it is almost unanswerable because we cannot reproduce the issues you are having. Also, please try to make the example as short as possible - be sure to remove any commented-out calls (such as `my_server.send_periodic()` and `writer.drain()` in the current question) or unnecessary code (`KeyboardInterrupt` handling). Aim for brevity and reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol code contains a typo, it names the method `data_deceived` instead of `data_received`. Once the method name is corrected, the output becomes the same as in the blocking example.

In the coroutine version, the problem is that `reader.read()` instructs asyncio to collect the data until end-of-file, and provide it when ready. Changing it to `reader.read(1024)`, in analogy with `sock.recv(1024)` in the blocking version, fixes the code.